# Django E.408, E.409 and E.410 errors on runserver

Tags: python, django, admin

I am installing a new Django project using virtualenv, all in the normal way. My version of Python is 3.7.3, and django is 2.2.3.

If I do python manage.py runserver, I get the following errors:

```
?: (admin.E408)'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware' must be in MIDDLEWARE in order to use the admin application.
?: (admin.E409) 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware' must be in MIDDLEWARE in order to use the admin application.
?: (admin.E410) 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware' must be in MIDDLEWARE in order to use the admin application.
```

Here is my settings.py, and you can see that those middleware are there.

```
"""
Django settings for fcc_new project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.9.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = MY KEY goes here

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'fcc_new.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'fcc_new.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

I've tried reinstalling, checking versions, and changing 'MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES' to 'MIDDLEWARE'. Nothing is working. Can anyone identify the problem?

Comment: `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` should 100% be renamed to `MIDDLEWARE`. Has the correct settings file been set in manage.py?

Comment: Hi Iain, I think the issue is that django-admin should be installing a newer version of startproject. I'm using zsh and googling has suggested that's the issue. But all of my versions are correct...I don't really get it. I'll check manage.py

Comment: Looks like you have multiple versions of Python with different versions on Django installed

Comment: Hi Iain, the fact that MacOS has Python 2.7 installed automatically has been the bane of my (and I'm sure others') life. I've just reinstalled my global django install and it's fixed the issue. Thanks for your help. Hopefully this thread will help others so I'll leave it up.

Comment: No problem, I have run into this issue many times. Maybe your virtualenv was not activated?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In Django 2.2.3, activating middlewears in settings is done using the variable `MIDDLEWARE` not `MIDDLEWERE_CLASSES`, check the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/middleware/#activating-middleware).

So simply **change the variable in your `settings.py` from `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` to `MIDDLEWARE`**.

Most likely this issue occurred due to creating a project with a global `django` package that had was of version < 2, and then running `manage.py runserver` with a virtualenv that has local `django` >= 2

Comment: "most likely ..." - no guessing please, and nothing like that. The reason is much simpler, Django's codebase has been changed. I quoted in my answer, Django's code raising the error.

Comment: For me, the "most likely ..." phrase is correct/applicable. I was testing a project created during the days of `django` version < 2 (actually, version 1.11.3), while I am running `django` 3.0.4. Renaming `MIDDLEWARE_CLASS` to `MIDDLEWARE` solved the problem.

Answer (score 10):

Rename variables in `settings.py`, or add this:

```
MIDDLEWARE = MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES
```

to `settings.py`
because new Django triggers errors above based on checks like this:

```
if not _contains_subclass(
   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
   settings.MIDDLEWARE
):
   errors.append(checks.Error( ...
```

Answer (score 7):

Change setting.py as pic shows
[Change setting.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDFQ7.png)

```py
# MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    # 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Also See: [From CSDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56923576/django-e-408-e-409-and-e-410-errors-on-runserver)

Answer (score 5):

1) Go to settings.py of your project

2) Cut these three lines from MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES :

```
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
```

3) Now paste the code given below right after MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES :

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
]
```

Will look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

change like it and keep the both ke `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` and `MIDDLEWARE` classes

```
 MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    # 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

---

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',  
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom middleware, try to import it in `manage.py shell`. Sometimes Django can blame other middlewares when it cannot import yours (because of not installed dependency for example).